# Search and Destroy with JQuery

Tags: jquery

What's the best way to ensure that all of the options selected only occur once?


For example:

1. User selects "SSN" from col_1 select box
2. User then selects "Last Name" from col_2
3. User then mistakenly selects "SSN" from col_3

I want to be able to clear (value="") the previous select box where SSN was selected (col_1)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("select").change(function(){

        var selectedColVal = $(this).val();                 
        var selectedCol = $(this).attr('id');

        //todo: see if currently selected value has already been selected
        //and clear the previous selectbox


    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="col_1">
      <select id="column_1" name="column_1">
         <option value="">Select Column Name</option>
         <option value="First Name">First Name</option>
         <option value="Last Name">Last Name</option>
         <option value="Email">SSN</option>
      </select>
</div>
<div id="col_2">
      <select id="column_2" name="column_2">
        <option value="">Select Column Name</option>
        <option value="First Name">First Name</option>
        <option value="Last Name">Last Name</option>
        <option value="Email">SSN</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="col_3">
  <select id="column_3" name="column_3">
    <option value="">Select Column Name</option>
    <option value="First Name">First Name</option>
    <option value="Last Name">Last Name</option>
    <option value="Email">SSN</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("select").change(function(){

        var selectedColVal = $(this).val();                 
        var selectedCol = $(this).attr('id');

        // find select (except current) that has same value selected
        var $tmp = $("select:not(#" + selectedCol + ") option[value='" + selectedColVal + "']:selected").parent();
        // clear value
        $tmp.val("");
    });

});
```

[live sample](http://jsfiddle.net/pP2Jp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selects = $("select"); // cache
    selects.change(function () {
        var self = $(this),
            others = selects.not(self);
        others.each(function (i, elem) {
            var other = $(elem);
            if (other.val() ===  self.val()) {
                other.val('');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kUHh5/